# Windows phone 8 push notification null channel uri

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone, mpns

I know this has been brought up many times but couldn't find an answer for it.

I am trying to set up push notifications in my app using the below code however I am running into the channel uri null problem.

I have tried the app on 4 different devices + emulator all under the same network conditions (Work WiFi - Home WiFi - 3G) 2 of the devices are Lumia 920 both could not obtain a channel uri, while the other 2 devices an HTC 8X and a Lumia 820 can successfully obtain channel uri and register for push.

The emulator also can obtain a channel uri successfully.

On one of the Lumia 920's it managed to get a channel uri, but I uninstalled and installed the app again and since then couldn't get any channel uri.

Below are my scenarios:

1- Lumia 920 Black installed on 3G worked fine, uninstalled/reinstalled stopped working on any connection (3G - Work WiFi - Home WiFi)
2- Lumia 920 Yellow installed on 3G - Work WiFi - Home WIfi never managed to get a channel uri
3- HTC 8X on 3G - Work WiFi - Home WiFi worked great on all 3 networks
4- Lumia 820 same as HTC 8X worked great

Please note that push notifications on other apps are working fine on all 4 devices.

I'd greatly appreciate any feedback/advice for the channel null uri

Below is the code I used, it is the same code as provided by MSDN

```
  public MainPage()
    {
        /// Holds the push channel that is created or found.
        HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

        // The name of our push channel.
        string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

        InitializeComponent();

        // Try to find the push channel.
        pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

        // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
        if (pushChannel == null)
        {
            pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

            // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
            pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

            pushChannel.Open();

            // Bind this new channel for toast events.
            pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

        }
        else
        {
            // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
            pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

            // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
                pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Also suffering from this on Lumia 820. Have tried disposing and re-creating the HttpNotificationChannel if the URI is null. Makes no difference. The URI starts null and there are no ChannelUriUpdated raised.

Comment: im restoring my lumia 920 black now, hopefully if it does not brick on restore I will test it out and post my results here... if any has any solution please help

Comment: ok so after my lumia 920 got bricked and managed to fix it, I can happily say that it managed to fetch a channel uri successfully from first launch and push is working fine... anyone has any ideas why it wasn't able to fetch a channel uri before restore?

Comment: Seems users are noticing that are issues with WP8 notifications. Search for "windows phone notification problem".

Comment: Sometimes when you develop apps with PNS and debug them a lot, you have to wait before continuing.

Comment: @Eran did you ever sort out this problem? I'm having the same null Uri issue on handset also!

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced the same issue. And it got resolved by setting my HTC windows phone with correct date and time.Once I set the date and time automatically, My hybrid application wp8 successfully registered pushplugin and received MPNS Channeluri.

Answer (score 0):

The ChannelUri was null because the new phone I was developing on would not set it's date and time correctly.  Once I switched the time to be set manually, then fixed it's time, date and region and then switched it back to auto, everything worked fine such as ssl certificates, windows phone update and most importantly a ChannelUri ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try going into settings > "phone + SIM" and turning off the "Data connection" option this sometimes does the trick?

Have you tried changing the options in settings > data sense? There are options there that restrict background data?

Is battery saver enabled? This limits usage when battery is low etc.

Also as mentioned above, Have you checked the date and time on the device? Maybe it's caused by the auto setting of date and time. You can fix this manually then switch back to auto. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a local wifi connection rather than the cell phone data connection. Disabling the phones "Data connection" as per one of the comments here will achieve this result. Although I tried this and failed it lead me to noticed that my phone was not connected to our wifi router.

NOTE: In my case we have very bad cell coverage so we use a special vodafone router that redirects all our cell phone data, calls, etc thru our fixed line Internet connection. Once I bypassed the that router I received a ChannelUri. I also tried the phone/app at work which uses a different cell tower and that was fine.

Answer (score -1):

I tried setting the date manually but to no effect. What ended up working for me was to actually start the phone without the SIM card, shut down, re-insert SIM and start again. This allowed me to get a ChannelUri again.

Suspect this could be related to the suggestion of [TripVoltage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2946386/tripvoltage) who suggests [toggling the SIM's data connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25607792/3711120).